# How to use scipy.optimize.minimize for function with 3 variables?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to optimise this function:

```
def voce(strain, sigma_s, sigma_y, epsilon_0):
    stress = sigma_s - (sigma_s - sigma_y)*np.exp(-strain/epsilon_0)
    return stress
```

by finding the best values for sigma_s, sigma_y and epsilon_0. Strain and stress should be 1 dimensional numpy arrays.

I've tried:

```
initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]
result = minimize(voce, initial_guess)
```

but I get "ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar"

I'm a bit confused how to use minimise this

Comment: You say `stress` should be a 1-dimensional array. However `scipy.optimize` can only optimize scalar functions: "Minimization of scalar function of one or more variables." (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the function you like to optimize? Is it the Voce equation?

Comment: Would you like to fit the voce equation on your stress-strain data? and need the optimized parameters for that purpose? right?

Answer (score 0):

The function to be optimized by scipy.optimize.minimize should return a scalar value. Please see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

That being said, you can implement a for-loop and solve stress for each strain value. Afterward, you can take the sum of the stress values and minimize the sum.

Before that, you need to first re-structure your VOCE function as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def voce(sigma_s, sigma_y, epsilon_0, strain):
    stress = sigma_s - (sigma_s - sigma_y)*np.exp(-strain/epsilon_0)
    return stress
```

Now, for optimization, introduce a new function, say *fun*, where you will pass `sigma_s`, `sigma_y`, and `epsilon_0` to be minimized and `strain` (1-D array) as an argument for your VOCE function:

```
def fun(x, strain):

    sigma_s = x[0]
    sigma_y = x[1]
    epsilon_0 = x[2]

    stress = []
    sum = 0

    for i in strain:
        s = voce(sigma_s, sigma_y, epsilon_0, i)
        stress.append(s)

    sum = np.sum(stress)

    return sum
```

Now, optimize and print the result as follows:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# strain = [x,y,z] <-- Assign your strain array here
initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]
res = minimize(fun, initial_guess, method="Nelder-Mead", args=(strain))
print(res)
```

Furthermore, if you want to fit the VOCE equation to your stress-strain data (meaning you already have measured stress values from an experiment), you can compare the results (calculated stress) of the VOCE equation with the measured stress using mean squared error from `sklearn`. For this, you could change the *fun* as:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

def fun(x, measured_strain, measured_stress):

    sigma_s = x[0]
    sigma_y = x[1]
    epsilon_0 = x[2]

    calculated_stress = []
    error = 0

    for i in measured_strain:
        s = voce(sigma_s, sigma_y, epsilon_0, i)
        calculated_stress.append(s)

    error = mean_squared_error(measured_stress, calculated_stress)

    return error
```

where `measured_stress` is a 1-D array. Now, optimize and print the result as follows:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# measured_strain = [x,y,z] <-- Assign your measured strain array here
# measures_stress = [a,b,c] <-- Assign your measured stress array here
initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]
res = minimize(fun, initial_guess, method="Nelder-Mead",
               args=(measured_strain, measured_stress))
print(res)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30706304)

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi I have tried to improve my answer now.